# ASP.NET MVC Request ServerVariables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using `ASP.NET MVC`, and need to obtain and log Request Information.

I'm looking at `Microsoft​.AspNetCore​.Http.HttpRequest` and do not see `ServerVariables`.  Has this been removed?

Is there a way I can get to the same data as I could via `System.Web.HttpRequest.ServerVariables`?

Thanks!

Philip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Microsoft​.AspNetCore​.Http.HttpRequest` is as the namespace says part of asp.net core. The `ServerVariables` is a collection of variables provided by `IIS`. As asp.net core does not depend on `IIS` this property doesn't exist anymore.

---

If do not use asp.net core [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx) is the `HttpRequest` class to use.

Comment: Wow ... thanks.  Could you please explain ... if I don't use ASP.NET Core, can I still use MVC, and get to this data?

Comment: @PhilipTenn then you need to use this [`HttpRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance ... when I am in a Controller method and I call to `Request`, I get the `Microsoft​.AspNetCore​.Http.HttpRequest` version.  How can I get the `System.Web.HttpRequest` version?

Comment: @PhilipTenn This would mean to me that you are using asp.net core... So you cant.